# How to config @RetryTransaction in Spring?

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I get this error  :

```
Getting “Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction”
```

I'm trying to resolve it using annotation RetryTransaction with @Transactionnal.

But the annotation cannot be resolved to a type.

What is the config to set in spring-config.xml to make it work ? or maybe supplementary dependecies to install ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling a bit reveals that the annotation you mentioned is not from spring, but someone else produced it.

You can get the maven artefact that contains it from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.dellroad/dellroad-stuff/1.0.659